# Inserting Dropdown list option in Table Cell

Tags: html, asp.net

I am trying to design the table with 2 rows and 3 columns. In the first row would be Header row with headings of Columns. And in 2nd row 1st column would be Editable Text area and 2nd column and 3rd column would be Dropdown list. I am using HTML table to achieve this. But not able to getting the dropdown option.

This is my code for Table

```
<div id="MainContent_panelConfigFileContent">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Start Position</th>
                <th>Type of Scramble</th>
                <th>Scrambling Required</th>
            </tr>                                                  
        </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: you could use ASP controls like Textbox and Dropdownlist to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
                         <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
      <div class="row modalpop-body"> 
         <table>
         <thead>
          <tr>
        <td class="col-md-4">Start Position</td>
        <td class="col-md-4">Type of Scramble</td>
        <td class="col-md-4">Scrambling Required</td>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
        <td class="col-md-4"><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea></td>
        <td class="col-md-4"><div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
         </ul>
         </div></td>
        <td class="col-md-4"><div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
               <span class="caret"></span></button>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
          </ul>
         </div></td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
          </table>
          </div>
```

CSS `.modalpop-body {background: brown;margin:30px;font-size:24px;padding: 20px;}`

you can check it in [check this link](https://jsfiddle.net/sus_hill/1mtcs757/18/)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing but are you referring to something like this?

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Header 1</td>
            <td>Header 2</td>
            <td>Header 3</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Your Editor</td>
            <td>Your Dropdown</td>
            <td>Your Dropdown</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Yes sir. Exactly same like this

Comment: So did this helped you?

Comment: somewhat helped. but not completely.

Comment: fiddle would be more batter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete. Try to give a better code to understand. Thank you

Comment: <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="row"> 
<div id = "modal-header" style="position: fixed; z-index: 999; height: 8%; width: 100%; top: 0; left:0; background-color: brown"></div>
</div></div> <div class="row"> <div class="modalpop-body">                              <div id="MainContent_panelConfigFileContent">
 <table class="table">
<tbody><tr>
<th>Start Position</th>
<th>Type of Scramble</th>
<th>Scrambling Required</th></tr>
 </tbody></table></div></div>                                                                                                              This is only I wrote

Comment: Please edit the question to give this feedback @kiran and this is not answer rather put your suggestion on comment Sus Hill.